# Storing string data with compressed (buffer) data together on Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

Is there any chance to store Buffer data with a string data together on Redis.

Pseudo code:

```
// Data compression
var user = { name: "Xyz" }
var userString = JSON.stringify(user)
var userBuffer = new Buffer(userString, "utf8")
var compressed = zlib.gzip(userBuffer)
// Adding data onto Redis
var data = { id: 1, compressed: compressed }
var dataString = JSON.stringify(data)
redis.set("test", dataString)
```

Although it seems impossible I wanna ask.

Is there any chance to store compressed data with string together?

**Edit:**

After storing compressed data with uncompressed data in the same key, I cannot decompress the user data above.

Pseudo code:

```
var dataString = redis.get("test")
var data = JSON.parse(dataString)
console.log(data) 
// writes { id:1, compressed: { type: Buffer, data: [31, 139, 8...] } }

var compressed = data.compressed
var user = zlib.gunzip(compressed)
// user would be undefined here
```

Comment: Its not very clear what you are asking here. Are you saying you want the compressed *and* uncompressed data in the same key? What string are you referring to?

Comment: Should work - what pseudo error are you getting?

Comment: @OliviaRuth actually yes. I want to store compressed and uncompressed data in the same key.

Comment: @ItamarHaber I've edited the question. I guess, I cannot `set` or `get` as `buffer` from Redis. If I compress the all data I can get the all data and I can decompress the all data successfully. I'd tried both of `ioredis` and `node_redis` libraries. I guess only one data type can store on a `key`. Because when reading the data the libraries must be decided whether the data would be read is a `buffer` or not.

Comment: @ItamarHaber also problem might be `JSON` operations which are parsing and stringifying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const zlib     = require('zlib');
const redis    = require('redis').createClient();
var user       = { name: "Xyz" }
var userString = JSON.stringify(user)
var userBuffer = new Buffer(userString, "utf8")
var compressed = zlib.gzipSync(userBuffer)
var data       = { id: 1, compressed: compressed }
var dataString = JSON.stringify(data)

console.log('Compressed', dataString);
redis.set('mykey', dataString, err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  redis.get('mykey', (err, dataString) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    var data         = JSON.parse(dataString)
    var buffer       = Buffer.from(data.compressed);
    var uncompressed = zlib.gunzipSync(buffer);

    console.log('Uncompressed', JSON.parse(uncompressed));
    redis.end(false);
  })
});
```

The key is to convert the string-representation of the Buffer back to a proper instance before decompressing it (using `Buffer.from()`).

However, the JSON-representation of a `Buffer` isn't very concise, so you probably should look into an alternative way of storing the data in Redis (one where you don't have to stringify the buffer). Perhaps using [a hash](https://redis.io/commands#hash).

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact I have to store compressed data on a sorted set. Because of I thought that if I store this static data as compressed, I can send to the clients directly (without compression at every time for every user). And it might be beneficial when considering the CPU cost and time complexity.

Comment: If you're using sets, perhaps you shouldn't use JSON but something like [`msgpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msgpack), to prevent buffers being encoded as string-based objects (although `msgpack` is slower than JSON, so the tradeoff is raw speed vs storage demands). There's also [`protobufjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs).

Comment: Thanks again. I'll check them out.